# Trying to set Alt Gr+Keycode 50 to backslash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I've just started running Linux Mint, However I'm using a slightly different keyboard hardware wise.

It had a multitude of issues in the start, such as Shift being mapped wrongly, atastrophe/asterisk not being mapped at all, however I've managed to fix that using XModMap.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = less greater backslash"
```

Is my Keymap for Keycode 50, and the first two works, but backslash doesn't I've tried repeating the backslash a couple of times to fix it, but haven't managed to fix it.

Xev Output Edit

```
KeyPress event, serial 270, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 9366403, (859,242), root:(1128,662),
state 0x90, keycode 50 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 270, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 9366483, (859,242), root:(1128,662),
state 0x91, keycode 50 (keysym 0x3e, greater), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3e) ">"
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 270, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0xd4, subw 0x0, time 9366523, (859,242), root:(1128,662),
state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Try running `xev` in a terminal and type a backslash while xev's window has focus. Look for KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp events in the output. That will tell you how X is registering the key press.

Comment: The thing is, I can't type backslash at all. Backslash naturally lies at Alt-Gr+< (Keycode 50 in my case), but It doesn't in this case.

Comment: A screenshot of the keyboard layout according to the keyboard settings in Mint. https://i.imgur.com/i41v35S.png

Comment: Some combination of physical keys maps to the \ character. By giving that combination of physical keys to `xev` you will see how X registers these key presses, which should help you set up your xmodmap settings.

Comment: Made an edit with the output of my `xev`, I can't seem to figure out how to do it.